# How can i remove a localStorage value from a string, without hardcoding the value?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm messing around with JS and localStorage, creating a todo-list. When an item in the list is clicked, it changes its CSS class, and it *should* be deleted from localStorage. The value of the item is decided by the user, so i cant hardcode in

```
localStorage.removeItem('Do the dishes');
```

for example.

I have tried doing this:

```
localStorage.removeItem(ev.target.innerText);
```

(longer version below). It doesn't give me an error, but it also doesn't remove the item from localStorage.

```
var taskList = document.querySelector('ul');

taskList.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');

    let tasks;
    if(localStorage.getItem('tasks') === null ){

        tasks = [];

    }
    else {
        tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));  
        console.log("TaskList Is Not empty"); 

        tasks.forEach(function(task, index){
            if(ev.target.innerText === task){
                localStorage.removeItem(ev.target.innerText);
                console.log("Removed"); 
            } 
            else{
                console.log("Else Executed");
            }
        }
```

The tasks are all added to a localStorage key called "Tasks":

```
function storeTaskInLocalStorage(newTask){
let tasks;
if(localStorage.getItem('tasks') === null ){
    tasks = [];
}else{
    tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
}
tasks.push(newTask);
localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
}
```

As stated, the item *should* be gone from localStorage, but it isn't. It's probably a fault in my code, but i can't seem to find any other way of doing it on the internet, so any help would be much appreciated!

If the full project is needed to troubleshoot or anything, just let me know and i can upload it to codePen or something :)

Comment: Can you show an example of the related HTML please? Does `ev.target.innerText` contain the _content_ of the item, or its _key_ (i.e. its identifier)? The [removeItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem) function requires you to supply the key.

Comment: what is value of `ev.target.innerText`

Comment: The value of ev.target.innerText is whatever the user says it is.. Lets say a user adds a task, "Wash my car", the ev.target.innerText becomes "Wash my car"

Comment: Ok. But what _key_ do you use to store that in the localstorage? Do you make the key the same as the content? Or do you generate another value?

Comment: The problem is that your tasks are under `tasks` key in `localStorage` and what you are doing is remove item from `localStorage` under key `ev.target.innerText`. I believe you should remove it from `tasks` and then save it again

Comment: can you show me where it is set in the first place

Comment: aDyson, it contains the content, not the key.. So.. is there no way of removing it? o.0

Comment: As a guess, from what you've shown above, it looks like you maybe store all the items under one "tasks" key as a JSON object? So everything is under a single localstorage item. Is that right? I can't see how you add the items to begin with, so I'm just inferring from the code you've shown above. If so then what you actually need to do is remove the item from the JSON (i.e. your `tasks` variable), and then write that back to the localstorage under the same "tasks" key, because you haven't got individual storage items you can remove, instead you've got a single stored item which you need to edit

Comment: aDyson I store them all in "Tasks", so do you have any idea how i could delete the ones that the user selects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should do the job:

```
var taskList = document.querySelector('ul');

taskList.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
  if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');

    let tasks;
    if (localStorage.getItem('tasks') === null) {

      tasks = [];

    } else {
      tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tasks'));
      console.log('TaskList Is Not empty');

      const taskId = tasks.indexOf(ev.target.innerText);

      if (taskId !== -1) {
        tasks.splice(taskId, 1);

        localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks));
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I hope that `tasks` is an array of strings where you store your todos - if not please tell me so I'll adapt code.

Comment: @Kashkashio it's very similar yes but I just extended my comment from post - "The problem is that your tasks are under tasks key in localStorage and what you are doing is remove item from localStorage under key ev.target.innerText. I believe you should remove it from tasks and then save it again" :)

Answer (score 1):

You have an error between the keys you setting and removing...
you try to

```
localStorage.removeItem(ev.target.innerText);
```

while the key you set is:

```
localStorage.getItem('tasks')
```

What you should do is to edit the Array you just parsed and save it again under the same key after JSON stringify or save it under different keys

Answer (score 1):

You need to set it as

```
localStorage.setItem('taskName', 'Do the dishes');
```

then you can remove it as

```
localStorage.removeItem('taskName');
```

In case you have an array of items you can do

```
const tasks= [];
task.push('Do the dishes');
task.push('Wash the car');
localStorage.setItem('taskName', JSON.stringify(task));
```